# jQuery - Connect more then 2 divs to each other

Tags: jquery

I can't manage to make sure I can connect more divs. Can somebody help me with this? I need to best way to manage this. The black boxes are the divs. I want connect with with a red line, always in the middle.

[image]

I used the following script:

http://jsfiddle.net/cnmsc1tm/

```
function connect(div1, div2, color, thickness) {
var off1 = getOffset(div1);
var off2 = getOffset(div2);
// bottom right
var x1 = off1.left + off1.width;
var y1 = off1.top + off1.height;
// top right
var x2 = off2.left + off2.width;
var y2 = off2.top;
// distance
var length = Math.sqrt(((x2-x1) * (x2-x1)) + ((y2-y1) * (y2-y1)));
// center
var cx = ((x1 + x2) / 2) - (length / 2);
var cy = ((y1 + y2) / 2) - (thickness / 2);
// angle
var angle = Math.atan2((y1-y2),(x1-x2))*(180/Math.PI);
// make hr
var htmlLine = "<div style='padding:0px; margin:0px; height:" + thickness + "px; background-color:" + color + "; line-height:1px; position:absolute; left:" + cx + "px; top:" + cy + "px; width:" + length + "px; -moz-transform:rotate(" + angle + "deg); -webkit-transform:rotate(" + angle + "deg); -o-transform:rotate(" + angle + "deg); -ms-transform:rotate(" + angle + "deg); transform:rotate(" + angle + "deg);' />";
//
alert(htmlLine);
document.body.innerHTML += htmlLine; 
}

function getOffset( el ) {
var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
return {
    left: rect.left + window.pageXOffset,
    top: rect.top + window.pageYOffset,
    width: rect.width || el.offsetWidth,
    height: rect.height || el.offsetHeight
};
}

window.testIt = function() {
var div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
var div2 = document.getElementById('div2')
connect(div1, div2, "#0F0", 5);
}
```

Comment: Are all your divs the same height like in the image? And have same position relative to top?

Comment: You can use jsplumb to achieve this

Comment: @Adder, all div's have the same height, but the layout has 3 different div rows. Row 1= 7 boxes, Row 2= 3 boxes, Row 3= 5 boxes. All they need to connect.

Comment: Maybe place a red-filled div with absolute positioning behind the boxes by adjusting the z-Index of the boxes and the red-filled div in css such that the red-filled div is behind the boxes.